# Turn "Keywords/Tokens" in view to HTML helper code

Tags: asp.net-mvc

In ASP.NET we have an editor that allows editors to type in content. We would like the functionality to enter some custom pre-built widgets/modules by simply typing in as an example:

```
[Facebook-Comments]
```

Then store that in the database.

When we are rendering the Page, we would like to parse any occurrences of [Facebook-Comments] or any widgets we have and turn them into either:

```
<% Html.RenderPartial("Facebook"); %>
```

or hopefully a subroutine of some sort where I can parse or run the code through another action (kind of like the `RenderAction`, but that is not included in this release)

Once this is done, feed it through to the normal life cycle of how a Page gets rendered.

What is the best approach of accomplishing this?

Comment: I like the idea. Do you have a specific question?

Comment: actually I am trying to figure out how to accomplish the above.